# How would I write a pandas apply lambda function that compares the value to the same index value in an outside list?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a simple dataframe and also a list of numbers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':[1,2,3,4,5]})
list_of_nums = [0,3,2,5,6]
```

I want to create 'column2' in df based on whether the respective row value is greater than or less than the respective index in list_of_nums.

column2 would be:

```
['Greater','Less','Greater','Less','Less']
```

I was trying something like this:

```
def compare_to_list(row):
    if row > list_of_nums[row.index]:
        return 'Greater'
    else:
        return 'Less'

df['column1'].apply(lambda x: compare_to_list(x))
```

However it's not able to access the row index in order to index the corresponding value in the list.

Comment: `np.where(df['column1'].gt(list_of_nums,axis=0),'Greater','Less than or equal to')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to compare the column with the list and assign `Greater` / `Less` accordingly, as follows:

```
df['column2'] = np.where(df['column1'] > list_of_nums, 'Greater', 'Less')
```

Result:

```
print(df)


   column1  column2
0        1  Greater
1        2     Less
2        3  Greater
3        4     Less
4        5     Less
```

Answer (score 0):

try via `pd.Series()` method and `map()` method:

```
df['column2']=((df['column1']>pd.Series(list_of_nums))
               .map({True:'Greater',False:'Less'}))
```

Output of `df`:

```
    column1     column2
0   1           Greater
1   2           Less
2   3           Greater
3   4           Less
4   5           Less
```